# How to fill form fields with model values

Tags: django

I am trying to fill my form with data from model Good. I use filter by id to get certain objects. I've needed to rewrite init function to set a working queryset, and it works. Now I need to fill values for other fields.

This is my forms.py:

```
class GoodGet(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Good_Get
        Size = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Good.objects.all())
        Name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'value': Good.objects.all()}))
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, good_id1=None, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if good_id1 is not None:
            obj = Good.objects.filter(id = good_id1)
            for good in obj:
                good_sizes = good.Size.all()
            self.fields['Size'].queryset = good_sizes
```

I need to do something like this:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, good_id1=None, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if good_id1 is not None:
            obj = Good.objects.filter(id = good_id1)
  --->      self.Name = obj.Name    <---
            for good in obj:
                good_sizes = good.Size.all()
            self.fields['Size'].queryset = good_sizes
```

So, how can I fill the values of other fields with data from model Good?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value to:

```
def __init__(self, *args, good_id1=None, **kwargs):
    super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if good_id1 is not None:
        obj = Good.objects.get(id=good_id1)
        self.fields['Name'].initial = obj.Name
        self.fields['Size'].queryset = obj.Size.all()
```

We thus use `Good.objects.get(..)` to retrieve the `Good` object that matches the given id, and we pass the `Name` attribute of that object as `.initial` value for that field.

But if it is only a matter of initializing a `ModelForm` with the values of an object, you can use the [**`instance=`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values), like:

```
# construct a form with data from an instance
GoodGet(instance=Good.objects.get(id=some_id))
```

That being said, there are some strange parts in your `GoodGet` form. It is probably better to add a `Form` suffix, you specify fields in the class, not in the `Meta` class, and using `{ 'value': Good.object.all() }` makes no sense, since the value can not be a set of `Good` objects.

```
class GoodGetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Size = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Good.objects.all())
    Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput()}))
    class Meta:
        model = Good_Get
        fields = '__all__'

    # ...
```

Comment: @FunCreator: but you likely did not use the `obj.Name` then?

Comment: The error is likely here: `widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'value': Good.objects.all()})`, this makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thank you for help, u are right. But I made a little change

Comment: @FunCreator: but you can slighly improve that, by using `obj.Size.all()`, since in the proposed solution `obj` is now a `Good` *object*, not a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, good_id1=None, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if good_id1 is not None:
            obj = Good.objects.filter(id = good_id1)
            self.fields['Name'].initial = Good.objects.get(id=good_id1)
            for good in obj:
                good_sizes = good.Size.all()
            self.fields['Size'].queryset = good_sizes
```

It must be like this in my case